# Parse through two files and concatenate strings into one file using bash

Tags: bash, grep, concatenation

I have two text files which I would like to parse through, then combine the two lines parsed into one file using a `grep` call. For example:

```
Foo.txt                  Foo2.txt
*1                        A
 2                        B
*3                        C
 4                        D
*5                        E
```

I would like to have

```
FooFinal.txt
 2B
 4D
```

I am attempting to use the grep command as so

```
grep -A 1 '*' Foo.txt|grep -v '*'
```

but, I am not sure how to grep both files.

I would assume one would use a `paste` command to concatenate, but I am not sure.

Also, if this is difficult to understand, please let me know so I can clarify.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Answer for revised question

```
$ paste -d '' foo.txt foo2.txt | grep -v '^\*'
 2B
 4D
```

#### Answer for original question

```
$ paste -d '' foo.txt foo2.txt | grep '^\*'
*1A
*3C
*5E
```

#### How it works

- `paste -d '' foo.txt foo2.txt`

  This combines the two files line by line.  The option `-d ''` tells paste to combine the lines directly with no intervening whitespace.
- `grep '^\*'`

  This selects only those lines which begin with `*`.

  For the revised question, we add `-v` which inverts the match: `grep -v '^\*'` *removes* the lines that start with `*`.

Comment: I am sorry, but I had a typo and I have now edited. What you had is great for what I originally had; however, I am wanting a different output than I previously posted.

Comment: @branch.lizard See updated answer for inverted output.

Comment: Excellent! Your updated solution works properly for the updated problem.